# R - export a function (not an object) in all clusters

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, lapply

I use **pblapply()** to run code in parallel. It gives a progression bar, which is useful. I use function like **clusterExport()** or **clusterEvalQ()** to export objects or librairies into clusters. But I didn't manage to share a home-made function, available in my environment. Can you help me with this ?

Here is an very basic example:

```
# home-made function
mean_by_column <- function(j){ 
  mean(iris[,j])
}

# this will produce error: could not find function "mean_by_column"
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2)

result_list <- pbapply::pblapply(
  cl = cl,
  X  = 1:4,
  FUN = function(j){ mean_by_column(j) }
)

# this will work
result_list <- pbapply::pblapply(
  cl = cl,
  X  = 1:4,
  FUN = function(j){ mean(iris[,j]) }
)
```

It works when I rewrite the whole function within the pblapply FUN argument, but I don't want to use it, because the real home-made function is very long, and I would like to apply such a code several times, I don't want to rewrite the whole function each time. Moreover, it will not be optimal if I want to modify the home-made function later, or if I want to make some debugg.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A function is an object.

Comment: you're right, it worked with `clusterExport(cl = cl, varlist = c("mean_by_column"), envir = environment())`, I tested it before with no success, don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function is an object as well.

You can therefore export it using `parallel::clusterExport(cl, "mean_by_column")`.